# Google Plus API nextPageToken error

Tags: google-plus

We are iteratively performing queries against the Google Plus API.  They all look like the following query, where the `pageToken` value is changed on each iteration, updated with the `nextPageToken` from Google's response to the previous query.

`https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities?maxResults=20&orderBy=recent&query={OUR QUERY}&pageToken={GIVEN PAGE TOKEN}&key={OUR API KEY}`

[The Google+ reference](https://developers.google.com/+/api/#pagination) indicates that the `nextPageToken` should be absent from Google's response on the last page of results.  However, this is what we experience: once we've apparently reached the last page of results, we keep receiving `nextPageToken` values along with an empty result set in the `items` field; the `nextPageToken` value changes on each iteration.  This pattern repeats itself several times until one of the `nextPageToken`s finally results in a 500 error.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=406). You should star the issue to show your interest in having it fixed.

Comment: Thanks, abraham!  I just starred it.